# Zimbabwe Satelitte Imagery

Tags: geospatial, africa

I need a high resolution map of an area in Zimbabwe; Google maps just isn't doing it good enough for me. 
Specifically, I'm seeking 5 areas all within 1 farm. The coordinates are

-17.607872, 30.478440
-17.599700, 30.487746
-17.597962, 30.483809
-17.610236, 30.486348
-17.606459, 30.483873

Comment: Your title says *imagery*, your text says *map*. Which is it ([edit] your question)?

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are lookkng for and I'd check them out:

https://openaerialmap.org/

https://cidr.cr.usgs.gov/login/?RET_ADDR=https%3A%2F%2Fcidr.cr.usgs.gov%2F

https://www.datadoors.net/DataDoorsWeb/Order.aspx

Good luck